# Unable to find column with logical name mapped exception

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

> I Use latest version of springboot 2.5.2 ,When I want to use One to
> Many relation ship I am getting some Mapping issue
> Here is the Issue

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(order) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

> order.kt

```
package com.main.serviceorder.entity

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
data class Order(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val oId:Long=-1,
    val orderNumber:String?="",
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "oli_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val orderLineItem:MutableList<OrderLineItem>?=ArrayList(),
)
```

> OrderlineItem.kt

```
package com.main.serviceorder.entity

import java.math.BigDecimal
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_line_items")
data class OrderLineItem(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val skuCode:String?="",
    val price:Float=0.0f,
    val quantity:Int=0
)
```

> I want to fectch OrderLineItem id in order table but it is not able to
> map the OrderLineItem Id in order table through OneToMany Relationship

Answer (score 0):

> To set OneToMany Relation ship between Order and OrderLineItem  need
> to pass Order Id in the refrencedcolumnName
> Like This
> Order.kt

```
package com.main.serviceorder.entity

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Order(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val oId:Long=-1,
    val orderNumber:String?="",
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "oli_id", referencedColumnName = "oId")
    val orderLineItem:MutableList<OrderLineItem>?=ArrayList(),
)
```

> OrderLineItem.kt

```
package com.main.serviceorder.entity


import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_line_items")
data class OrderLineItem(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val skuCode:String?="",
    val price:Float=0.0f,
    val quantity:Int=0,
    val order:Order
)
```